# template overload of trigonometric functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am developing a larger library, where I would like to be able to change the floating point precision used. Trigonometric functions are used in a number of places, so I decided to include templated wrappers for e.g. sine and cosine.

I have made the following simple example, which gives a stack corruption and I cannot figure out why. Any hints

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

namespace sps {
template <typename T>
inline T sin(const T& v) { return sin(v); }

template <typename T>
inline T cos(const T& v) { return cos(v); }

template <>
inline float sin<float>(const float& v) { return sinf(v); }

template <>
inline float cos<float>(const float& v) { return cosf(v); }
}  // namespace sps

template float sps::sin(const float& v);
template float sps::cos(const float& v);
template double sps::sin(const double& v);
template double sps::cos(const double& v);

int main()
{
  double d = 2.0;
  std::cout << sps::sin(d) << std::endl; /* (*) */
  float f = 2.0f;
  std::cout << sps::sin(f) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If I explicitly state, which functions to use, e.g. sps::sin(f), I still get a stack corruption. The stack corruption is thrown in the line with the asterisk (*). If I omit the explicit instantiations, the stack corruption still occurs. I tried changing the inputs to by-value, but this has no effect either.

I get the same error using gcc 6.3.0 and MSCV 2017.

Thanks in advance
Jens

Comment: `template <typename T> T sin(const T& v) { return sin(v); }` is infinite recursive...

Comment: The template (non-specialized) `sin` and `cos` functions, what functions do you think they call? You *do* know about *recursion*?

Comment: what is `sps` ? Btw are you sure that you want templates and not simply overloads?

Comment: Does not `sin(x)` all ready call different precision functions with `std::sin(float), std::sin(double)`?

Comment: @chux [Indeed they do](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin).

Comment: I know, the problem is that I am using them in some rather complicated functions, which are inlined and the functions are inlined again. I am facing some numerical difficulties where different contribution must cancel exactly. I need precision of about 120 dB

Comment: `inline` keyword is irrelevant to the function templates (it is relevant only to the function template explicit specializations).

Comment: @Constructor. I get compiler error if I apply inline to the explicit instantiations using GNU compiler. Anyway, I found my silly error.

Comment: The explicit specialization is not the same as the explicit instantiation.

Comment: You are right. It makes sense though to inline both the default case and the specialization - I would think

Comment: As I wrote before `inline` is irrelevant to the templates.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an infinit recursion:

```
template <typename T>
inline T sin(const T& v) { return sin(v); }  // keep calling sin
```

what you need is to change the return value to:

```
template <typename T>
inline T sin(const T& v) { return std::sin(v); } 
                                  ^^^
```